# Cannot push element to array after using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, prototype

So I have a simple class with few properties. Using prototyping I add few methods.These methods returns `this`, so I could chain tham together.

`Get` method finds all elements and puts into `allCurrentElements`, which is an array (or at least I think so). And when I use `CreateElement` method, it simply creates element and tries to push it to existing array `allCurrentElements`.

To use it, simply write `var a = _h.Get('p').CreateElement('div')`. And here is where I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.allCurrentElements.push is not a function(…)`.

If I try to assign newly created element using index it does not throw error however, this element does not appear in the array.

```
var _h = (function(){
    var Helper = function(){
        this.allCurrentElements = [];
    }

    Helper.prototype.Get = function(query){
        this.allCurrentElements = document.querySelectorAll(query);
        return this;
    }

    Helper.prototype.CreateElement = function(el, attr) {
        var elem = document.createElement(el);
        for (var a in attr) {
            elem[a] = attr[a];
        }

        //this.allCurrentElements[this.allCurrentElements.length] = elem;
        this.allCurrentElements.push(elem);
        return this;
    }

    return new Helper();
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldp58onu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check `Document.querySelectorAll()` documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Returns a non-live NodeList of all the matching element nodes.

NodeList are used very much like arrays and it's tempting to invoke Array.prototype methods on them, however NodeList objects don't have any of the familiar Array methods.

So you have to iterate through NodeList something like :

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(query), function(element){ 

        allCurrentElements.push(element);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

`document.querySelectorAll()`  returns `NodeList` which is an Array-like object.

The problem is that NodeLists are read-only. You'd need to transform it in an array. `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(query));`

after that you'll be able to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately I can accept only one answer :(

Comment: or just 
[].slice.call()
if you don't like to type too much :)